# Canonical, SiteMap and Index Files?

Tags: sitemap, canonical-link

I've set all my website URLs to be displayed without any index.* references, through .HTAccess, so making my canonical definitions simpler. My question is, does the sitemap.xml definitions also need to lose the index.* references?
Ultimate aim is not to confuse Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to give some examples for us to make **100%** sure we understand you correctly.

But yes, naturally your XML sitemap should reflect your real URLs :)

So if instead of somedir/index.html you now use somedir/ your XML sitemap should reflect that :)